# RabbitMQ subscription limit the number of messages to pre fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

I am using `rabbitmq` to communicate between `microservices` written in ruby on rails. Each service subscribes to a `topic`. All services are `scaled` and run as multiple instances based on need.

During subscription `bunny` moves *`all the messages`* from the queue into `unacked` state. This makes other scaled instances to be just idle, since there is no message in `ready` state.

Is there a way to limit the number of messages a subscription can fetch, so that other instances can take the remaining messages from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you made available, I'm assuming you're using [rubybunny](http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html). If this assumption is incorrect (there are other ruby clients available for rabbitmq) let me know and/or check the documentation related to your client.

Back to rubybunny, link provided points to necessary information, quoting it:

> For cases when multiple consumers share a queue, it is useful to be
>   able to specify how many messages each consumer can be sent at once
>   before sending the next acknowledgement.
>
> In AMQP 0.9.1 parlance this is known as QoS or message prefetching. 
>   Prefetching is configured on a per-channel basis. 
>   To configure prefetching use the Bunny::Channel#prefetch method like so:

```
ch1 = connection1.create_channel
ch1.prefetch(10)
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks. I was looking exactly for this.